# Windows form saving to file twice and appending

Tags: winforms, file-io, save, streamwriter

I have a windows form project I am working on. I have a menu strip with a save and and exit option.

When performing either action for the the first time, the file will be saved. The user is presented a dialog box, and then they choose the file name and path and it saves great.

But for additional saves, since a file already exists, it is suppose to overwrite the file, but instead it is appending to the end. So, in essence, it is outputting the same info twice to the file.

Here is the event handlers for the save and close:

```
private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        saveCurrentFile("save");
    }

    private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        saveCurrentFile("exit");
        this.Close();
    }
```

Here are the save methods:

```
private void saveCurrentFile(string sender)
    {
        // Check who called this method for the first time, if it was the save menu option, no need to ask if they want to
        // save, just show the user the prompt
        // If it was the exit menu option, ask user if they want to save
        if (sender.CompareTo("save") == 0)
        {
            if (fileName == "")
            {
                saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
                fileName = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
            }
        }
        else if (sender.CompareTo("exit") == 0)
        {
            // Display a messagebox to ask user if they want to save
            DialogResult dResult = new DialogResult();
            dResult = MessageBox.Show("Would you like to save?", "Save", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);

            // Check what button the user pressed
            if (dResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                if (fileName == "")
                {
                    saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
                    fileName = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
                }
            }
        }

        // Now check if the fileName is empty
        if (fileName != "")
        {
            DateTime date = DateTime.Now;

            // Add some header information to the string builder
            sb.AppendLine("Budget Information");
            sb.Append("Date & Time File Saved: ");
            sb.AppendLine(date.ToString());
            sb.Append("\r\n");
            sb.Append("\r\n");

            // Add the income data to the string builder
            sb.AppendLine("Hourly Wage: " + hourlyUpDown.Value.ToString("C"));
            sb.AppendLine("Annual Salary: " + annualUpDown.Value.ToString("C"));
            sb.AppendLine("Tax: " + taxUpDown.Value.ToString());
            sb.AppendLine("Hours Per Week: " + hoursPerWeekUpDown.Value.ToString());
            sb.AppendLine("Weeks Per Year: " + weeksPerYearUpDown.Value.ToString());
            sb.AppendLine("Net Weekly Income: " + netWeeklyIncome.ToString("C"));
            sb.AppendLine("Net Monthly Income: " + netMonthlyIncome.ToString("C"));
            sb.AppendLine("Net Annual Income: " + netAnnualIncome.ToString("C"));

            // Add the expenses table to the string builder
            foreach (KeyValuePair<TextBox, TextBox> entry in expenses)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(entry.Key.Text + " " + entry.Value.Text);
            }

            // Add a note to the user about modifying the file by hand
            sb.Append("\r\n");
            sb.Append("\r\n");
            sb.AppendLine("This file is created in a specific format.");
            sb.AppendLine("Any modifications to it may cause errors when the program tries to open and read the file contents.");
            sb.AppendLine("Any changes made by hand must conserve the formatting");

            using (StreamWriter outfile = new StreamWriter(fileName, false))
            {
                outfile.Write(sb.ToString());
                outfile.Flush();
                outfile.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

I am not sure why the file is having it written twice.
I added the `outfile.Flush()` and `outfile.Close()` to try and fix the problem, but that did not work.

Any help would be great.

---

Edit: I updated the code to only use one method to save.
The bug is a bit more complicated than I originally thought.

Each time the user goes to save the file, the output is appended to the file.
So if a user saves the file by going to Menu-> Save, the output is written to the file.
For each subsequent save, the output is appended.

Not sure what is wrong, I am using the boolean append parameter for the streamwriter, flushing and closing.

Comment: you know you can use only 1 fonction ? if instead you would use `StreamWriter(fileName, True)` it would create OR append the file by itself. so need for a function for creating and one for adding. I never liked using `Using()` using supposed to dispose and nullify the object after it ran but i had issue in the past where it didn't work properly and stop using it. You could give a try without, i'm no expert of Using.

Comment: @Franck - Thanks for the tips, I'll give them a try and clean up those save functions a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, my mistake.

I forgot to clear the stringbuilder contents after the file is written to and closed.

So, right after the `using(){}` statement, i use `sb.Clear()` to clear the string builder and now it works.

Just a side note, I did make sure the stream write object was created with the false boolean parameter to ensure overwriting of the file.